# Is there an attribute in MVC to limit Controller Actions to posts from a specific site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, referrer

I have an ajax call used to start the 'forgot password' process from an SPA to a controller in the MVC app that looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ResetPassword(User acct)
{
  ...
}
```

I was hoping there was a way to limit this controller to posts only from that page. I could write a custom attribute I suppose, but I was hoping this is a common enough problem that someone has already done that. And yes, I realize falsifying headers to contain spoofed referrer data is possible, but the added layer of security would give me a little more piece of mind. Or does anyone have a suggestion of a better way to accomplish the same thing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Given that people can still fake headers, I'd say that your "peace of mind" is probably more delusional than real (and I say that in a nice way.) You still will have to solve the bigger, overall security picture anyway, so what do you actually gain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. As noted, you could try to use the referrer header ([`HttpRequest.Referrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx)), but it's not reliable for a number of reasons:

- It's not a required header,
- You're depending on the rendering agent (e.g, the client browser) to set it [honestly], and
- It can be changed. For instance, if the request is proxied, it could be set to the proxy URL.

[`HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) is probably somewhat more reliable. But again, you can't really depend on it: it's the IP address the request came from, but again, if the request is proxied or coming through a firewall, you're likely going to get the proxy address, not the actual client IP address.

The most reliable way would be to implement client authentication via a certificate:

- http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication
- http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication

Though it's a bit of a hassle: the client has to provide the correct cert as part of the request and the server has to have the matching cert as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Is there a reason the anti forgery token suggestion above wouldn't be a good solution?

Comment: The anti-forgery token is to prevent cross-site request forgery, not to limit request by IP address. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After looking into the actual use for this, I've decided to go with client authentication; for our purposes the hassle is worth the added security.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [referer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) in HTTP. That gives you the page the request was made from.

Yes, you have to be mindful that this is not secure, as any HTTP header can easily be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use anti forgery token

http://kamranicus.com/blog/posts/70/protip-using-anti-forgery-token-with-aspnet-web-ap/

Comment: This would be perfect! I think I can tweak this to what I need. I'm not directly calling my API. JQuery is calling this MVC controller which (among other things) relays the request to the internal-only API. So I think can still use the the anti forgery token in a similar fashion to what they've done. Thanks!